# How to add two collections inside @Document annotation while developing POJO class?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

```java
@Document(collection = "first_collection",collection = "second_collection")
public class Foo {

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 1):

Providing multiple collection names is not supported.This annotation marks a class as being a domain object that we want to persist to the database.

Documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html